# Show the "Site Workflow"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have the following code that tries to list the Site Workflows. However, I am getting error on the line with ExecuteQuery()

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell Snap-in and Importing the SharePoint Online module
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Import-Module ‘C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell’ -DisableNameChecking

#Load SharePoint Client Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"


#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credential (Get-Credential)
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/")

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
{ 
    $web = $clientContext.Web
    $workflowServicesManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($clientContext, $web);
    $workflowSubscriptionService = $workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
    $workflowSubscriptions = $workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptions();
    $clientContext.Load($workflowSubscriptions);
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();   #<--- Error

    foreach($workflow in $workflowSubscriptions)
    {
        Write-Host $workflow.Path
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe a long shot but would you not need to call the Load() method for the two vars above workflowSubscriptions as well?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess that you're getting a "forbidden" error. I noticed that you're referencing both the SharePoint online module as well as the SharePoint CSOM assemblies. These are two different things with different sets of capabilities, and frustratingly, different authentication mechanisms. So you use "Connect-SPOService, authenticate with it, but then don't use those libraries again. Instead, you switch over to CSOM for the rest of the calls, but you've never authenticated for CSOM.

On the line after $clientContext=, I'd add the following:

```
$adminUsername = "admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$secureAdminPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString "please enter password"
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($adminUsername, $secureAdminPassword)
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials
```

Unless you're using it elsewhere in the script, you can get rid of the "connect-sposervice" call.